# Scrapy to crawl the data of private playlist in youtube?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I made the crawler using scrapy in python. But it is not working. It seemed to be succeed in authentication. But after this, it has to move to my private list and crawl every title of clips in the private list. But it doesn't work.

I think after it succeed in authentication, it goes other page unlike I expected

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'youtube'
    start_urls = ['https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            #formdata={'Email': 'xxx@gmail.com', 'Passwd': 'xxxx'},
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):

        print "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
        # print response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "yt-alert-message")]').extract()[1]
        print response.headers["x-frame-options"]
        print "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"

        # check login succeed before going on
        if "error-msg" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return

         # We've successfully authenticated, let's have some fun!
        else:
            return Request(url="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=xxxxxxxx",
               callback=self.parse_tastypage)

    def parse_tastypage(self, response):
        print response.xpath("//div[@class='pl-video-title']/a/@href").extract()
```

Comment: it isn't logging in for me